# Error: Unable to load the service index for source <URL> when adding to Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I created a CI/CD pipeline within a custom GitLab instance. In the pipeline I create and push the code as NuGet packages. Now I want to use GitLab as package source in Visual Studio and I get the error: `[gitlab] Unable to load the service index for source <URL>. Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)`.

[image]

[image]

When I try to go to this link in my browser I works just fine.

For setting this all up I was using [this documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/nuget_repository/). I already tried the following things:

- Using personal token / using repository token
- Cleared NuGet cache
- Cleared credentials and reentered them
- Check if the URL is correct

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What does that URL give you when you put it in your browser address bar? And it's hard to tell since you redacted the URL, but are you sure it is correct, does it contain the project id?

Comment: @DavidG the URL gives me the index of the nuget package registry in JSON format. So I think it looks alright in the browser

Comment: Does it work if you remove `/packages/nuget/index.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite strange that the sever cannot found your nuget source since the the URL can access correctly under the Website.

**So** please try the following steps to make a clean:

**1)** Close VS, delete `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config`

**2)** restart VS to generate the new global `nuget.config` file.

**3)** Close VS again, open the new clean `nuget.config` file and then add your github link under the file and also the [packageSourceCredentials info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesourcecredentials) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
      .......
      .......
    <packageSources>
     <add key="gitlab" value="https://xxxx/packages/nuget/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
      
    </config>

    <packageSourceCredentials>
     <gitlab>
      <Contoso>
        <add key="Username" value="xxx" />
        <add key="Password" value="xxx" />
    </Contoso>
     </gitlab>

   </packageSourceCredentials> 

</configuration>
```

**4)** save it and then restart your VS, try to install a nuget from that package source to test it.